# Date split pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do i split the following df:
Existing Dataframe

```
    t         t1
Test1   [October 22nd, 2019, February 8th, 2020, Augus...
Test2   [July 31st, 2020, September 21st, 2020, March ...

Desired Dataframe
    t         t1
Test1    October 22nd, 2019
Test1    February 8th, 2020
Test2    July 31st, 2020
Test2    September 21st, 2020
```

```
new_df.head().to_dict()
{'t': {0: 'Test1', 1: 'Test2'},
 't1': {0: [Date(22,10,2019),
   Date(8,2,2020),
   Date(8,8,2020),
   Date(8,2,2021),
   Date(11,6,2021)],
  1: [Date(31,7,2020), Date(21,9,2020), Date(21,3,2021), Date(11,6,2021)]}}
```

Tried code as per below

```
new_df["t1"]=new_df["t1"].float64.split(",")
print(new_df.explode("t1").reset_index(drop=True))
```

getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float64'
```

Comment: The dtypes don't make sense for your shown data. Could you include the output from `new_df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks for highlighting. Original question edited.

Comment: So it seems you already have a list. No need to split just explode. `new_df.explode("t1").reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @HenryEcker many thanks. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how `new_df` is constructed for you, but @Henry is on the right track and the following worked for me.

First I construct the dataframe:

```
data = {
    't': ['Test1','Test2'],
    't1': [
        [date(2019,10,22), date(2020,2,8), date(2020,8,8), date(2021,2,8), date(2021,6,11)],
        [date(2020,7,31), date(2020,9,21)]
    ]}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then the explode command to get what you want:

```
new_df.explode("t1").reset_index(drop=True)

Out:
       t          t1
0  Test1  2019-10-22
1  Test1  2020-02-08
2  Test1  2020-08-08
3  Test1  2021-02-08
4  Test1  2021-06-11
5  Test2  2020-07-31
6  Test2  2020-09-21
```

So long as each row in t1 is an array of datetimes, the above should work.